# Last image from JSON not showing

Tags: android, json, image, caching

I have a working JSON list, which contains images and descriptions.

Everything is working fine, but when I update my JSON file - so I add new item - new image and new description, then the newly added image is not showing in my listview on my phone.

The description is there, but not the last image. The other images are of course showing, only the newest isn't.

I tried to avoid caching, by adding `conn.setUseCaches(false);` to my HttpURLconnection, also I added MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE to Picasso when I retrieve the images, but nothing helped, the image is still not there.

**The only solution was to manually erase all memory and data for my application in my phone settings and only then the image is showing!**

Can you please advice, why the newly added image is not showing immediately from JSON? Because the description and other data is showing immediately, but the image isn't. Thank you.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(myList.get(position).getThumb()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(holder.thumb);
```

Comment: can you post some code for how you're retrieving the images & updating the JSON list?

Comment: i updated my question with the Picaso code - the way I am retrieving the image and now I used also .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) and it seems this helped. I need to test it by adding another new item to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue - the solution with .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) worked.